# Is it possible to retrieve the commit ID of the current HEAD without first cloning the repository using GitPython (or more generally Git)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, version-control

I am developing a program that should analyze the contents of Git repositories, if they have changed (i.e. the commit ID of the current `HEAD` has changed)

Since there are more than 10.000 repositories, and only a relative few of them are under active development, I'd like to avoid having to clone all of them before checking the commit ID of their current `HEAD`.

Does GitPython support this - and more generally, does Git support checking the value of refs without cloning the repository?

**NB**: I could do a `clone --bare --depth 1 <repo> [<dir>]` to only retrieve the objects of the latest commit, without checking out `HEAD`, which would speed up things up considerable. However, I'd still need to download all objects of the latest commit, which is still wasted effort, if I only want to check the commit ID of the current `HEAD`.

**NB**: The Git service provider (Stash) doesn't support `clone --filter ...` option, which could have been used to avoid downloading any blobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git ls-remote` :

```
git ls-remote repo-or-remote master
```

will give you the hash of master (you can check for any branch)

```
git ls-remote repo-or-remote
```

will give you the hashes for all available refs on the remote, use `--heads` to see only the branches

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful! Is the the canonical way of doing it? Do you have any experience with `GitPython`, i.e. how to execute `git ls-remote` through it?

Comment: Look in the docs how to execute any command, there is a class for this, pretty easy to find

Comment: Do you mean `git.cmd.Git`? If so, I find it inconvenient that I've to call `g.init()` in order to execute `ls-remote`? See here: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.cmd

Comment: `ls-remote` can be called from outside a repo, if you provide a url (and not a remote name). The example shows how to call known commands, it does not say that it is compulsory to call `git.init()`. It conveniently shows how to call a command with a `-` in its name (replace it with `_`)